# It says here: The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

Tags: symfony

```
<?php
namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction($name)
  {
    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
  }

  public function newAction(Request $request)
  { 
    // just setup a fresh $task object (remove the dummy data)
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) 
    {
      $form->bind($request);

      if ($form->isValid()) 
      {
        // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It says here:  The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?
Can anyone help me on this

Comment: possible duplicate of [error no response symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766887/error-no-response-symfony2)

Comment: if ($request->isMethod('POST')) 
{
  $form->bind($request);

if ($form->isValid()) 
{
// perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
 }
  }
}                                                         return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
'form' => $form->createView(),
   ));
}

Answer (score 1):

if `if($request->isMethod('POST'))` returns `false` you don't do anything. So when you create for the first time your form (and you aren't into `POST` case), you run into this situation and you have to return something to your controller action caller.

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) 
{
  $form->bind($request);

  if ($form->isValid()) 
  {
    // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
  }
}
// here, you have to return something (view,xml,redirect,etc...)
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer @DonCallisto but i still dont have a clue what to do, i think programming using Symfony is really hard and i feel like giving up but i will not. This question i had posted is on this site http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html. i followed the instructions till handling form submissions and got stuck , please any kind soul can help. I'm really really at a lost and really need help

Comment: @raffryan: programming with symfony is anything but difficult.. first of all you have to know what to do if you're not posting to this controller action. after that, if you have right ideas, I can point you to a solution ...

Comment: alright @DonCallisto , give me some time, I'll try to sort it out. If there's anything, is it possible to get back to you? Thanks alot, i have been playing with this application for 3-4 days only

Comment: @raffryan: yes, if I can help I'll do. What I suggest here is to study ALL symfony2 system before "start playing" or, eventually, study "component" every time you meet them